# AppBar color secondary with Select material-ui-next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `beta 33` of `material-ui-next`:

```
import * as mui from 'material-ui';
```

In a component, I have an `AppBar` with a `ToolBar` and a `Select`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <mui.AppBar color="secondary">
      <mui.Toolbar color="secondary">
        <mui.Select color="secondary" value={0}>
          <mui.MenuItem value={0}>First Item</mui.MenuItem>
        </mui.Select>
      </mui.Toolbar>
    </mui.AppBar>
  );
}
```

The `AppBar` has the secondary color I set in a theme. The `Select` keeps the primary colors. What is the proper way to set the `Select` to use the secondary colors as well?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Select/Select.js#L103), Select doesn't have a color prop. Depending on what aspect you are trying to color, you can use one of [these](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/) methods.